# Combine .csv rows based on shared fields (linux and/or python)

Tags: python, linux, csv

I have .csv files that list file names and the date and time they were created for all the images in the directory. The images are in pairs that share the same date and time. I need to rearrange the .csv file so that file names that share the same date and time are separate fields, but in the same row.

Currently, it looks like

```
01010001.JPG,01:01:2021 1:00:00
01010002.JPG,01:01:2021 1:00:00
01020003.JPG,01:02:2021 2:00:00
01020004.JPG,01:02:2021 2:00:00
```

and I need the output to look like

```
01010001.JPG,01010002.JPG,01:01:2021 1:00:00
01020003.JPG,01020004.JPG,01:01:2021 2:00:00
```

Is there a simple way to do this, either directly in the Linux command line or with a python script? All of the rows that need to be combined are pairs and are in consecutive rows, so something that merges every other row together would work, as would something that actually combines them based on the shared value in the date field.

Comment: Do the corresponding pairs of files always appear in subsequent rows, i.e. 1st and 2nd row, 3rd and 4th row etc? Please [edit] your question to provide this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear as to if you need to combine alternate rows or combine based on date, but regardless in your case, you can use sql for that. Here is an example in mysql

```
create table Test(id integer primary key, title longtext, datet longtext);

insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(1, "01010001.JPG", "01:01:2021 1:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(7, "01010007.JPG", "01:01:2021 1:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(2, "01010002.JPG", "01:01:2021 1:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(3, "01020003.JPG", "01:01:2021 2:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(4, "01020004.JPG", "01:01:2021 2:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(5, "01030005.JPG", "01:01:2021 3:00:00");
insert into Test(id, title, datet) values(6, "01030006.JPG", "01:01:2021 3:00:00");

select concat(group_concat(title),",",datet) from Test group by datet;
```

and this is the output

```
concat(group_concat(title),",",datet)
01010001.JPG,01010007.JPG,01010002.JPG,01:01:2021 1:00:00
01020003.JPG,01020004.JPG,01:01:2021 2:00:00
01030005.JPG,01030006.JPG,01:01:2021 3:00:00
```

there are ways to import your csv into mysql so you can skip the insert queries, but once you have done that this should do the trick

Comment: I tried this out and the output did combine rows by their shared date, very helpful, thanks! However, the output placed the whole row in quotation marks making it one field. Do you know of a way to execute this without adding those quotation marks?

Comment: Well that might happen due to it being exported as a string. Try it in some database viewer which can export as csv. I tried it in mysql workbench and it worked fine. In the answer the result is from an online mysql interpreter [Paiza MySQL](https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=mysql). It would help if you let us know what exactly did you use.